# How is "accuracy" calculated using Libsvm - SVM_Predict.exe

Tags: python, machine-learning, svm, libsvm, prediction

I am using the LIBSVM for the first time.
I was able to train a data(for images) and my model is ready "trainingdata.svm.model"

Now, when I run my classification against an unknown test data it is giving me two files:
1. trainingdata.svm.prediction (This file contains 1's and 0's) against my each of test data.
2. It is giving me Accuracy = 8 %

**THE QUESTION:**
1. How do I interpret the 1s and 0s in my "trainingdata.svm.prediction". Note: I am classifying genders where 1 could be male and 0 could be female.

2. How is Accuracy calculated? How can a program calculate accuracy since the test data is an unknown entity and we do not know the labels yet.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. The file "trainingdata.svm.prediction" is predicting the labels 1 and 0 for your set (1 means the sample was predicted to be male, 0 is female).
2. It assumes all the labels belong to class index 0, I believe.